# How to find the derivative using first principle formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the derivative (slope of tangent) of x = 6 of the following function using only the methods of first principles only.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}}$$

*I am very confused on how to solve this question using first principles. I know that the answer is $\frac{-1}{16}$ but I don't know how to get it. Can anyone please show me how to get to the answer or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Here's what I did:
[image]

Later on, I tried to get the answer but got something similar to it. I tried rationalizing the single expression by itself before putting it together with the whole equation. Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

[image]

Comment: Suppose $h \neq 0$ and compute $f(x+h)-f(x)$ over $h$. Next, compute the limit of that expression as $h\to0$.

Comment: Adding to @Azif00 comment above, notice that $f(6) = 1/2$. So first compute the expression $\frac{f(6+h) - 1/2}{h}$, and then see if you can take the limit. Write out as much as you can and say where you are stuck. Otherwise it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: A couple of observations about your notes: $2\sqrt{4-h} - (4 - h) = 2\sqrt{4-h} -4+ h \neq 2\sqrt{4-h} - 4 - h$; also, $\sqrt{4-h} \neq \sqrt{4} - h$ (not even approximately equal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to finally achieve the answer that was correct. Here's my work:
[image]

If I have made any errors, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of curiosity, I propose another way to calculate the derivative of $f$:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}} & \Rightarrow \ln f(x) = -\frac{\ln(x-2)}{2}\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = -\frac{1}{2(x-2)}\\
& \Rightarrow f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2(x-2)^{3/2}}
\end{align*}

Hence the equation of the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(6,f(6))$ is given by
\begin{align*}
y = f(6) + f'(6)(x - 6) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{(x - 6)}{16}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}} - \frac{1}{2}
= \frac{2-\sqrt{4+h}}{2\sqrt{4+h}}
= \frac{(2-\sqrt{4+h})(2+\sqrt{4+h})}{2\sqrt{4+h}(2+\sqrt{4+h})} \\
= \frac{4-(4+h)}{2\sqrt{4+h}(2+\sqrt{4+h})} 
= \frac{-h}{2\sqrt{4+h}(2+\sqrt{4+h})}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)$ be a curve. Then

taking increments by both sides in $x$ and $y$, we have

$y+∆y=f(x+∆x)$

$∆y=f(x+∆x)-y$

Since $y=f(x)$

$∆y=f(x+∆x)-f(x)$

Divide both sides by ∆x, we have

$∆y/∆x=(f(x+∆x)-f(x))/∆x$

When ∆x→0 then

$lim ∆y/∆x$

$∆x→0$

$=lim (f(x+∆x)-f(x))/∆x$

$∆x→0$

$f^{'}(x)=$

$lim (f(x+∆x)-f(x))/∆x$

$∆x→0$

This is known as derivative by first principle method.